# React hook for scrolling window to top of element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make hook for scrolling window to top of element by changing condition:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { scrollToWindowTop, getElementCoordinates } from "modules/utils";

export default function useScrollToRefTop(offsetY = 0, condition = null) {
  const elementRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (elementRef.current) {
      // firstly I was trying this way to get element top position according to document top
      // const top = elementRef.current.offsetTop; 
      const { top } = getElementCoordinates(elementRef.current);
      const topOffset = Math.round(top + offsetY);

      scrollToWindowTop(topOffset);
    }
  }, [elementRef, condition, offsetY]);

  return elementRef;
}
```

as `condition` I'm using lication change `location.pathname`. Each time by changing location I got the same `top` value? but only first time window scrolls correctly, and each next times scrolls randomly, as it seems to me ). I would be very grateful if someone would help me where I was wrong?

**Using**:

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useScrollToRefTop } from "modules/hooks";

const Component = () => {
 const { pathname } = useLocation();
 const elementRef = useScrollToRefTop(0, pathname);

 return (
    <div ref={elementRef}>
      ...something
    </div>
  )

}
```

**scrollToWindowTop** helper:

```
export default function scrollToWindowTop(top = 0) {
  const scrollOptions = {
    top,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  };

  try {
    window.scrollTo(scrollOptions);
  } catch (error) {
    window.scrollTo(top, 0);
  }
}
```

**getElementCoordinates** method:

```
export default function getElementCoordinates(element) {
  var box = element.getBoundingClientRect();

  var body = document.body;
  var docEl = document.documentElement;

  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
  var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docEl.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;

  var clientTop = docEl.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
  var clientLeft = docEl.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

  var top = box.top + scrollTop - clientTop;
  var left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft;

  return {
    top: top,
    left: left
  };
}
```

Comment: so basically to a particular element you need to scroll is that whats the issue ?

Comment: Do you just need to scroll a specific element into view, or scroll the element to be at the top of the current view?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you are trying to achieve can be achieved with an anchor link if I understood correctly.

Example

```
<a href="#scroll-here">This is where the location pathname changes then, right?</a>

<div id="scroll-here">Should scroll to top of this<div>
```

Comment: He might want an animated scroll?

Comment: Possibly, but I would not recommend doing that.